# RTNETLINK error file exist

Tags: 16.04, networking

After editing the /etc/network/interface file to:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.x.y
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.x.254
dns-nameservers 192.168.z.z 192.168.z.z
```

I tried to restart the interface in several ways. I tried ifdown ifup, /etc/init.d/networking restart and even a reboot of the machine.
When trying the reboot the machine will not restart....
When trying to restart the service it gives the error "RTNETLINK answers: File exists"
I have tried to flush the "ip addr flush dev eth0", but no help there....

the file is wright, and the location to. When i replace static with dhcp and hash out the rest o fth config it works fine.

I'm a bit lost here....

Can anyone help me?

greetz Wim

Comment: Found out that the device keeps putting out a DHCP request even after setting the config to "static"

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation? is network-manager running?

Comment: its a server installl and network-manager isn't running